# `undefined reference` error occurred when linking dynamic c++ lib with CGO

Tags: go, dynamic-linking, cgo, dynamic-library

I use dynamic libaray written by c++ in my Go code as following:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L lib -ldemo
#include "demo.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
   C.demo() // demo function in c++ library
}
```

The `libdemo.so` library depends on the system dynamic libaray such as `fontmanager`

There are `undefined reference` errors occurred when I run the Go code, the errors detail as following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libdemo.so: undefined reference to `FT_GlyphSlot_Own_Bitmap'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libdemo.so: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Color_Glyph_Layer'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libdemo.so: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Glyph_Name'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libdemo.so: undefined reference to `FcLangSetCreate'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libdemo.so: undefined reference to `FcFontSetMatch'
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libdemo.so: undefined reference to `FT_Get_X11_Font_Format'
... more ...
```

I try to use `ld` command as following:

```
ld /mycode/lib/libdemo.so   # Same `undefined reference`

ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/font-manager/libfontmanager.so /mycode/lib/libdemo.so 
# Link successful
```

I guess I should include all dependencies in Go Code, but I don't know how to include the references of dynamic libraries in Go code，or include multiple dynamic library in Go code.

Scene1:

```
`GoCode` include `DynamicLibA`
`DynamicLibA` include `DynamicLibB`
```

Scene2:

```
`GoCode` include `DynamicLibA`
`GoCode` include `DynamicLibB`
```

FIRST QUESTION:
**Is this problem caused by not including all the dependent libraries？**

SECOND QUESTION:
**In above 2 scenes, How to include the libraries in Go code？**

Please give some suggestion, THANKS A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this problem caused by not including all the dependent libraries？

Yes. More precisely, the `libdemo.so` was not linked correctly -- it *should* be linked with `-lfontmanager`, and wasn't.

> `ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/font-manager/libfontmanager.so /mycode/lib/libdemo.so`

This command is *pure nonsense*. It doesn't do *anything*.

The command you want (you should *never* use `ld` on a UNIX system, unless you are linking an operating system, a boot loader, or something similar):

`gcc -shared -o libdemo.so demo.o -lfontmanager`